# how to apply reshape data.frame multiple column in r?

Tags: r

I'm trying to reshape a dataframe, but I'm not succeeding, everything is going wrong

```
  x=read.table(text="Bacia  Classe2 ano Area_ha2
1   Agricultura 2005    1215.027534
1   Área_descoberta 2005    2.24527708
1   Área_úmida  2005    0
1   Área_urbana 2005    0
1   Corpo_hídrico   2005    0
1   Pastagem    2005    535.9559549
1   Veg_Nativa  2005    54.13612516
1   Agricultura 2006    1222.844425
1   Área_descoberta 2006    2.24527708
1   Área_úmida  2006    0
1   Área_urbana 2006    0
1   Corpo_hídrico   2006    0
1   Pastagem    2006    527.6401139
1   Veg_Nativa  2006    54.63507562
1   Agricultura 2007    1226.337078
1   Área_descoberta 2007    1.081059335
1   Área_úmida  2007    0
1   Área_urbana 2007    0
1   Corpo_hídrico   2007    0
1   Pastagem    2007    524.3137775
1   Veg_Nativa  2007    55.63297655
1   Agricultura 2008    1218.187554
1   Área_descoberta 2008    1.081059335
1   Área_úmida  2008    0
1   Área_urbana 2008    0
1   Corpo_hídrico   2008    0
1   Pastagem    2008    532.7127769
1   Veg_Nativa  2008    55.38350132
", 
sep = "", header = TRUE)

View(x)
```

reshape(x, idvar="ano", timevar="Classe2", direction = "wide")

i hoped it:

[image]

Comment: Your code is pretty much right. Just add `Bacia` to the `idvar=` argument - `reshape(x, idvar=c("Bacia", "ano"), timevar="Classe2", direction="wide")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(x, names_from = Classe2, values_from = Area_ha2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another tidyr option

```
x %>%
tidyr::spread(Classe2, Area_ha2, fill = "NA")
```